# Spring resource found but no beans are loaded

Tags: java, spring

I am importing a spring xml configuration file from another project using import resource. The resource is apparently found since there is no error message saying it isn't, but none of the beans get loaded. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I should note that when I run my integration tests from within eclipse it all works fine, but it blows up when running the same integration test from within a maven build.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:httpclient-4x.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.data" />

<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:properties/client.${deployment.env}.properties</value>
         </list>
    </property>
         <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

</beans>
```

httpclient-4x.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<bean id="secureRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="secureClientHttpRequestFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML" />
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" />
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="secureClientHttpRequestFactory" class="com.cobalt.inventory.security.PreemptiveBasicAuthClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="secureCloseableHttpClient" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="secureCloseableHttpClient" factory-bean="secureHttpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="secureHttpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultCredentialsProvider" ref="credentialsProvider" />
    <property name="defaultSocketConfig" ref="socketConfig" />
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
    <property name="userAgent" value="${http.user.agent: CDK Cobalt invJava}" />
    <property name="maxConnPerRoute" value="${http.max.connections.per.route:100}" />
    <property name="maxConnTotal" value="${http.max.connections:100}" />
</bean>

<bean id="credentialsProvider" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider" />

<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
    <constructor-arg index="0" name="userName" value="validUsername" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="password" value="validPassword" />
</bean>

<bean id="socketConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig.Builder">
    <property name="soKeepAlive" value="true" />
    <property name="soTimeout" value="${http.socket.timeout:10000}" />
</bean>
<bean id="socketConfig" factory-bean="socketConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig.Builder">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="${http.connection.timeout:10000}" />
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="${http.socket.timeout:10000}" />
    <property name="cookieSpec">
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />


<!-- For accessing common authorization service -->

<bean id="commonAuthzSecureRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="commonAuthzSecureClientHttpRequestFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML" />
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" />
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
                <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                            <bean id="jsonMediaTypeApplicationJson" class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                                <constructor-arg value="application" />
                                <constructor-arg value="json" />
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="commonAuthzSecureClientHttpRequestFactory" class="com.mycompany.security.PreemptiveBasicAuthClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="commonAuthzSecureCloseableHttpClient" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="commonAuthzSecureCloseableHttpClient" factory-bean="commonAuthzSecureHttpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="commonAuthzSecureHttpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultCredentialsProvider" ref="commonAuthzCredentialsProvider" />
    <property name="defaultSocketConfig" ref="commonAuthzSocketConfig" />
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="commonAuthzRequestConfig" />
    <property name="userAgent" value="${http.user.agent: userAgent}" />
    <property name="maxConnPerRoute" value="${http.max.connections.per.route:100}" />
    <property name="maxConnTotal" value="${http.max.connections:100}" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonAuthzCredentialsProvider" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider" />

<bean id="commonAuthzCredentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
    <constructor-arg index="0" name="userName" value="${common_services.iam.remoting.user:user" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="password" value="${common_services.iam.remoting.password:password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonAuthzSocketConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig.Builder">
    <property name="soKeepAlive" value="true" />
    <property name="soTimeout" value="${http.socket.timeout:10000}" />
</bean>
<bean id="commonAuthzSocketConfig" factory-bean="commonAuthzSocketConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="commonAuthzRequestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig.Builder">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="${http.connection.timeout:10000}" />
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="${http.socket.timeout:10000}" />
    <property name="cookieSpec">
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="commonAuthzRequestConfig" factory-bean="commonAuthzRequestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<util:list id="spel-configuration">
    <value>#{credentialsProvider.setCredentials(T(org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope).ANY, credentials)}</value>
    <value>#{commonAuthzCredentialsProvider.setCredentials(T(org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope).ANY, commonAuthzCredentials)} </value>
</util:list>

</beans>
```

I turned debug logging on for Spring and found the following log entries:

```
[2015-04-13 10:46:56,818][DEBUG][org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:httpclient-4x.xml]
[2015-04-13 10:46:56,818][DEBUG][org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader] - Imported 0 bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:httpclient-4x.xml]
```

I do not have control of the content of httpclient-4x.xml I just reference it.

By request, here is CvsDataClientImpl:
    package com.mycompany.data;

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.mycompany.utility.ConditionalUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

@Component
public class CvsDataClientImpl implements CvsDataClient<JsonNode> {

private static final int MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 100;

private static final String V1 = "/rest/v1.0/vehicles";

@Resource(name = "secureRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Resource(name = "jsonVehiclesNodeMerger")
private JsonVehiclesNodeMerger nodeMerger;

@Value("${inv.vehicle-app.context:inventoryWebApp}")
private String vehicleAppContextPath;

@Value("${services.remoting.url:http://localhost:10080}")
private String remotingUrl;

@Override
public JsonNode read(String urlParameters) {
    validateUrlParameters(urlParameters);
    ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(buildBaseRestUrl() + "?" + urlParameters, JsonNode.class);
    return response.getBody();
}

@Override
public JsonNode readAll(String urlParameters) {
    return readAll(urlParameters, null);
}

public JsonNode readAll(String urlParameters, Integer pageSize) {
    int offset = 0;
    int actualPageSize = pageSize != null ? pageSize : MAX_PAGE_SIZE;
    JsonNode latestResult = null;
    JsonNode baseResult = null;
    do {
        String extendedUrlParameters = buildUrlParameters(urlParameters, offset, actualPageSize);
        latestResult = read(extendedUrlParameters);
        baseResult = merge(latestResult, baseResult);
        offset += actualPageSize;
    } while (latestResult.get("searchResult").get("vehicles") != null);
    return baseResult;

}

private JsonNode merge(JsonNode latestResult, JsonNode baseResult) {
    JsonNode merged = null;
    if (baseResult == null) {
        merged = latestResult;
    } else {
        merged = nodeMerger.merge(latestResult, baseResult);
    }
    JsonNode searchResult = merged.get("searchResult");
    ((ObjectNode) searchResult).remove("summary");
    return merged;
}

private String buildUrlParameters(String urlParameters, int offset, int pageSize) {
    String parameters = urlParameters;
    parameters += "&limit=" + pageSize + "&offset=" + offset;
    return parameters;
}

private String buildBaseRestUrl() {
    return remotingUrl + vehicleAppContextPath + V1;
}

private void validateUrlParameters(String urlParameters) {
    if (ConditionalUtils.isNullOrEmpty(urlParameters) || urlParameters.indexOf("inventoryOwner") < 0 && urlParameters.indexOf("storeId") < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide at least an inventory owner or store ID");
    }

}

void setVehicleAppContextPath(String contextPath) {
    vehicleAppContextPath = contextPath;
}

void setRemotingUrl(String remotingUrl) {
    this.remotingUrl = remotingUrl;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you have another file named httpclient-4x.xml in your classpath? classpath* is way too broad in finding the resource. You might want to turn on spring logging at debug and see where httpclient-4x.xml is loaded from.

Comment: Good thought, but no, there is no other file named httpclient-4x.xml on my classpath. To be sure, I also looked at the spring debug logging that I quoted from in my question and those two lines are the only mention of the file--there is no entry telling me where it was loaded from.

Comment: When you say, blowup what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: [2015-04-13 10:46:57,263][WARN ][org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cvsDataClientImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'secureRestTemplate' is defined

Comment: Can you add your `cvsDataClientImpl` to your OP? I guess you are autowiring there..

Comment: @minion Done. See above.

Comment: If you have only one config file, try loading using `<import resource="classpath:httpclient-4x.xml" />`. If you use a * and if the file is not found, Spring won't complain. This should tell if it could the file or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75149/discussion-between-minion-and-smacdav).

Comment: We had discussion and apparently the built jar does not have the file in place. So he is going to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion on chat, minion and I found that httpclient-4x.xml is not included in the external project's build jar for some reason. Now I need to investigate that, but it's another story. :-)